# GWT : Code splitting leftovers

Tags: gwt, split, download

I made an application in mobile version and desktop my problem is that the.

I splitted it now in 3 parts

1.Part : entrypoint - do some DB calls and checks if it is mobile :

2.Part mobileEntrypoint : shows a login window in mobil

3.Part desktopEntrypoint : shows login window in desktop version

Desktop and mobile part have 3 different views, in the mobile part I call some classes which the desktopn version calls too.

how can I reduce the leftovers now, shall I split this 6 views too? or shall I splitt this classes which are called by both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish (smaller code for most users) can be easily done with a different feature of GWT called [Deferred Binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDeferred.html).

Deferred binding allows you to create different permutations of your app, for example, one for mobile and another one for desktop. The compiler will only include code necessary for each permutation when compiling it. This means that a mobile version will have no code that is used only in the desktop version, and vice versa.

Comment: thanks for teaching me again :), i will notic that point in my new project. I found a nice code splitting point (reduced my Initial download size from 4 to 1,2MB !! yuhee)